# When Running Rspec and Sinatra, I keep getting ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rspec2, argument-error

I've got a class method called authenticate, which works on the User class.

```
def self.authenticate(email:, password:)
  result = DatabaseConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '#{email}'")

  User.new(result[0]['id'], result[0]['email'])
end
```

I have an Rspec test;

```
feature 'authentication' do
  it 'a user can sign in' do
    User.create(email: 'test@example.com', password: 'password123')

    visit 'sessions/new'
    fill_in(:email, with: 'test@example.com')
    fill_in(:password, with: 'password123')
    click_button 'Sign In'

    expect(page).to have_content 'Welcome, test@example.com'
  end
end
```

When running Rspec, I get the following error;

```
1) authentication a user can sign in
     Failure/Error:
       def initialize(id:, email:)
         @id = id
         @email = email
       end

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
     # ./lib/user.rb:15:in `initialize'
     # ./lib/user.rb:23:in `new'
     # ./lib/user.rb:23:in `authenticate'
     # ./app.rb:84:in `block in <class:BookmarkManager>'
```

Below is my Sinatra app;

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require './lib/bookmark'
require './lib/user'
require './database_connection_setup.rb'
require 'uri'
require 'sinatra/flash'
require_relative './lib/tag'
require_relative './lib/bookmark_tag'

class BookmarkManager < Sinatra::Base
  enable :sessions, :method_override
  register Sinatra::Flash

  get '/' do
    "Bookmark Manager"
  end
  get '/bookmarks' do
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @bookmarks = Bookmark.all
    erb :'bookmarks/index'
  end

  post '/bookmarks' do
    flash[:notice] = "You must submit a valid URL" unless     Bookmark.create(url: params[:url], title: params[:title])

    redirect '/bookmarks'
  end

  get '/bookmarks/new' do
    erb :'bookmarks/new'
  end

  delete '/bookmarks/:id' do
    Bookmark.delete(id: params[:id])
    redirect '/bookmarks'
  end

  patch '/bookmarks/:id' do
    Bookmark.update(id: params[:id], title: params[:title], url: params[:url])
    redirect('/bookmarks')
  end

  get '/bookmarks/:id/edit' do
    @bookmark = Bookmark.find(id: params[:id])
    erb :'bookmarks/edit'
  end

  get '/bookmarks/:id/comments/new' do
    @bookmark_id = params[:id]
    erb :'comments/new'
  end

  post '/bookmarks/:id/comments' do
    Comment.create(text: params[:comment], bookmark_id: params[:id])
    redirect '/bookmarks'
  end

  get '/bookmarks/:id/tags/new' do
    @bookmark_id = params[:id]
    erb :'/tags/new'
  end

  post '/bookmarks:id/tags' do
    tag = Tag.create(content: params[:tag])
    BookmarkTag.create(bookmark_id: params[:id], tag_id: tag.id)
    redirect '/bookmarks'
  end

  get '/users/new' do
    erb :'users/new'
  end

  post '/users' do
    user = User.create(email: params[:email], password: params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect '/bookmarks'
  end

  get '/sessions/new' do
    erb :'sessions/new'
  end

  post '/sessions' do
    user = User.authenticate(email: params[:email], password: params[:password])
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect('/bookmarks')
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Please check your email or password.'
      redirect('/sessions/new')
    end
  end

  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

Below is the full User class

```
require_relative './database_connection'
require 'bcrypt'

class User
  def self.create(email:, password:)
    encypted_password = BCrypt::Password.create(password
    )
    result = DatabaseConnection.query("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES('#{email}', '#{encypted_password}') RETURNING id, email;")

    User.new(id: result[0]['id'], email: result[0]['email'])
  end

  attr_reader :id, :email

  def initialize(id:, email:)
    @id = id
    @email = email
  end

  def self.authenticate(email:, password:)
    result = DatabaseConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '#{email}'")

    User.new(result[0]['id'], result[0]['email'])
  end

  def self.find(id)
    return nil unless id
    result = DatabaseConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = #{id}")
    User.new(
      id: result[0]['id'],
      email: result[0]['email'])
  end
end
```

What I don't understand is, why is Rspec saying it was expecting 0 arguments, when the `initialize` method clearly requires two arguments (id, and, email)?
I need to take the id and email method from `authenticate` and deliver it to `initialize`.
I thought that's what I was doing, but both Rspec and sinatra are saying otherwise.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are passing id as sequential args (in the `authenticate` method).

```
User.new(result[0]['id'], result[0]['email'])
```

However your `User.new` expects keyword args:

```
def initialize(id:, email:)
```

Simply pass them this way:

```
User.new(id: result[0]['id'], email: result[0]['email'])
```

Also, just something I noticed, if your `DatabaseConnection.query` returns no results your `authenticate` will raise an error from `result[0]['id']` (it will say `"Undefined method [] for Nil:NilClass"`. Maybe you should fix this and add a test case for it, for example:

```
def self.authenticate(email:, password:)
  result = DatabaseConnection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '#{email}'"
  )
  record = result[0]
  if record
    User.new(id: result[0]['id'], email: result[0]['email'])
  end
end
```

This way the method will return `nil` if there's no matching user, and your `if user` inside `post '/sessions'` will work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You were right about keyword args. it also solved another Rspec error I got as well. As for returning no results, I have that covered with the following code `def self.authenticate(email:, password:)
    result = DatabaseConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '#{email}'")
    return unless result.any?
    return unless BCrypt::Password.new(result[0]['password']) == password
    User.new(id: result[0]['id'], email: result[0]['email'])
  end`

Comment: Yeah ... it also might be worth considering to use an ORM like datamapper or activerecord ... they're there to help not hurt :)